# Interpolating Function as PDF in Mathematica

Tags: interpolation, wolfram-mathematica, probability-density

I want to use interpolation of a function as a PDF and be able to use tools like Mean, Probability, CDF and so on. I did the following:

```
 f = Interpolation[data];
 dist = ProbabilityDistribution[f[x], {x,0,1000}];
```

And for example when I try:

```
Mean[dist] //N
```

it just returns input. The same thing with other other functions.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a discrete distribution:

```
data = {1, 2, 1, 3, 4};
data = data/Total@data;
f = Interpolation[data];
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[f[x], {x, 1, 5, 1}];
Mean[dist] // N
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also experiment with a SmoothKernelDistrubution.

```
d = SmoothKernelDistribution[data];

cdf=CDF[d]

Plot[cdf[x], {x, -1, 1}]

Quantile[d, 0.95]

Moment[d, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `EmpiricalDistribution` :

```
f = EmpiricalDistribution[data]

Mean[f]
(* 1/5 *)

Expectation[x^3, x \[Distributed] f]
(* 101/6655 *)

Moment[f, 2]
(* 31/605 *)
```